# Why or where should we use config.ru in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am not understand why config.ru file in rails3. Please explain why is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails server` does the basic job of creating a `Rack::Builder` object and starting the webserver. This is Rails’ equivalent of Rack’s `rackup` script.

Here’s how `rails server` creates an instance of `Rack::Builder`

```
app = Rack::Builder.new {
  use Rails::Rack::LogTailer unless options[:detach]
  use Rails::Rack::Debugger if options[:debugger]
  use ActionDispatch::Static
  run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
}.to_app
```

To use `rackup` instead of Rails’ rails server, you can put the following inside `config.ru` of your Rails application’s root directory:

```
# Rails.root/config.ru
require "config/environment"

use Rails::Rack::LogTailer
use ActionDispatch::Static
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

And start the server:

```
$ rackup config.ru
```

To find out more about different rackup options:

```
$ rackup --help
```

To know about more rakup please have a look [Ruby on Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html)